# How to take a file with JSP and Servlet and convert it into a Blob?

Tags: file, jsp, servlets, upload, blob

I need to upload a file in a database using an input form in a JSP. I use EJB and my Entity has a file attribute declared as `Blob`, so I need to convert the file uploaded.

How can I do?
I've read similar questions but they didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA engines should be able to store a byte array (`byte[]`) as a blob in the database. I would use `byte[]` rather than `Blob` for your entity field.

Comment: Thanks, the conversion worked, but I have other problems. I cannot get input parameters. If I use `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the form I am not able to get simple text input with `request.getParameter("name")`.

Comment: Use a web framework that supports file uploads, or use apache commons fileupload.

Comment: Done. Two more questions: 1 - Why should I use `byte[]` rather than `Blob`? 2 - When I store a file in my DB and open a table, I see a lot of strange characters and MySql crashes (maybe there are too many chars). Is there a way / format to avoid seeing them?

Comment: Because the Blob implementation is provided by the DB vendor. Entities are at a higher level, and a byte array is the most obvious, database-agnostic way to represent binary data. Regarding your MySQL crash, I have no idea. Is it MySQL which crashes, or the tool you're using to browse your database tables?

Comment: It's MySql (used via command line). So it isn't possible to hide the chars, isn't it?

Comment: The MySQL server doesn't crash, does it? I would use a higher-level tool like PhpMyAdmin or something like that. I don't know MySQL well, so I don't know if what you want is possible, but you can at least execute a query which doesn't select the blob column.

Comment: MySql Server does not crash. Anyway, I'll try to use a tool as you suggested. Thanks for all your replies.